# Type Redefinition of Struct In C++?

Tags: c++, struct

Got confuse of a C++ code snippet when I study C++, Could someone help me on this? Thanks In advance.

```cpp
struct LinkNode
{
  int data;
  struct LinkNode* next; // Why there use `struct` type define LinkNode again? 
};
```

As my comments, why there use `struct` type define LinkNode again? I think code `struct LinkNode{}` had already define a LinkNode. Of course, if I change the code as below, it works fine without any compilation error either.

```
struct LinkNode
{
  int data;
  LinkNode* next; // No any compilation errors either.
};
```

Comment: There should be no error for the 1st version, both are equivalent. Can you show the complete example, as well as the exact error message?

Comment: The first is what recovering C programmers write before they've kicked the habit. It's not a redefinition.

Comment: @cigien Yes, there is no error message during compile. I just confuse why there use `struct` "declare"(I thought it's declare) LinkNode again what means type redefinition.

Comment: No, it's an optional usage of `struct`. It's not a redeclaration. Check out "elaborated type specifiers".

Answer (score 1):

> Type Redefinition of Struct In C++?

This is not a type redefinition. This is called an elaborated type specifier. It can be used to disambiguate a class name from another name that hides it. It is not necessary to use it in this case. It also doesn't break anything to use it.

The code may be written for an API usable from C as well. In C, this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In the code

```
struct LinkNode
{
  int data;
  struct LinkNode* next; // Why there use `struct` type define LinkNode again? 
};
```

The line `struct LinkNode* next;` does not define a new type. It declares a member variable `next` of the (already existing) type `LinkNode`.

What threw you off here is probably the keyword `struct`, which, as you already figured out, is purely optional in this context. The reason why you are allowed to put `struct` here in the first place is a heritage from C. C distinguishes between tag names and type names. A declaration of the form `struct Foo {};` in C only introduces a tag name `Foo`, but not a type name. This means that to instantiate an object of `Foo` in C you would need to write `struct Foo f;`, with the `struct` keyword there to turn the tag name into the corresponding type.

To get a proper type name in C, you'd have to use a typedef:  `typedef struct Foo FooType;` which would then allow you to just write `FooType f;`. Since this distinction between tag names and type names proved to be not very useful in practice, C++ simply got rid of the distinction, allowing the simpler declaration notation you are familiar with.

Comment: As I understand it, C++ maintains the distinction, hence why elaborated type specifiers are possible, but it also injects tag names into the type name space too. Edit: searching briefly, I see this might be misremembered misinformation :-)

Comment: @underscore_d Although the wording of C++ may be different, I'm not sure if there is practical difference with types and tags having shared name space versus all tags implicitly having a type name.

Comment: @underscore_d C++ still has some machinery in there to support some of the weirder uses that are supported through C's tagging. See for instance the examples in [class.name](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name). However, it does not support *all* of C's use cases (in particular it bans redefining to an unrelated type via typedef), so it is a different system. Barring weird corner cases, just pretending tag types don't exist in C++ except for backwards compatibility with C is a very good approximation of truth in practice though.

Comment: @ComicSansMS, wow, what a good explanation, It solve my question about `typedef` keywork either. Very thanks. It help me a lot for a new learner.